# Most common value in flat list

Tags: python, list

What are some ways to get the most common value in a list?

```
l = [1,2,2]
```

So far I'm doing:

```
Counter(l).most_common()[0][0]
```

But I was wondering if there was a list method or something 'simpler' to do this?

Comment: If you're only after the most common, use `Counter(l).most_common(1)` as the `Counter` class optimises that use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), but it's not efficient as your current solution:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 2]
>>> max(set(l), key=l.count)
2
```

Answer (score 6):

That's pretty much as good as it gets - although I'd suggest using `.most_common(1)` which will be more efficient* than `.most_common()` and use it like so:

```
(value, count), = Counter(sequence).most_common(1)
```

*Source from `collections.Counter`:

```
if n is None:
    return sorted(self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is almost equivalent to what @JonClement 's solution does

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [1,2,2]
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> max(c, key=c.get)
2
```

As [`heapq.nlargest`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l434) will run

```
if n == 1:
    it = iter(iterable)
    head = list(islice(it, 1))
    if not head:
        return []
    if key is None:
        return [max(chain(head, it))]
    return [max(chain(head, it), key=key)]
```

in this specific case where `n=1` which performs the same as above just without the list of a single tuple.